# Remove white space between slides in Bootstrap 5 3D Carousel Slider

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I am using Bootstrap on my site and also use the carousel slider and it's working fine.

The problem is when the slider slides the image from right to left it will take a second image when the first image reaches completely to the left. This means that for 1ms or 2ms it will display a white space between slides. I don't want that white space and I want the slider to slide from the right to the left second image must immediately appear after the first one.

I want to create like this

[demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ECsAf.png)

```css
.carousel-item {
  perspective: 1000px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.carousel-item img {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.carousel-inner {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  /* Prevent items from wrapping */
  gap: 1rem;
  /* Add some space between carousel items */
  overflow: hidden;
  /* Hide the overflow to prevent extra spacing */
  perspective: 1000px;
}

.carousel-item {
  flex: 0 0 calc(33.333333% - 1rem);
  /* Calculate the width with gap */
  transform: translateZ(-200px);
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="carouselExample" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img src="https://placehold.co/800x400" class="d-block w-100" alt="Image 1">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="https://placehold.co/800x400" class="d-block w-100" alt="Image 2">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="https://placehold.co/800x400" class="d-block w-100" alt="Image 3">
    </div>
    <!-- Add more carousel items as needed -->
  </div>
  <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExample" data-bs-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
      </button>
  <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExample" data-bs-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
      </button>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

You can see white space there so I want my next image should appear after the previous image.

Comment: bootstrap carousel doesn't offer options like "how many sliedes to show", "how many slides to scroll", "center mode". Please consider slick slider as an alternative: https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/ "center mode" example is pretty close to what you're looking for,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need advanced carousels, you should use a library specialized on this, like: [Swiper](https://swiperjs.com/)

I don't recommend to use slick as GrafiCode suggested, it is not maintained since 2017.

Here is an example which looks what you want: https://codepen.io/iamdineshbasnet/pen/XWxpjaQ

```js
var swiper = new Swiper(".mySwiper", {
    effect: "coverflow",
    centeredSlides: true,
    autoplay: {
        delay: 3000,
        disableOnInteraction: false
    },
    loop: true,
    slidesPerView: "2",
    coverflowEffect: {
        rotate: 0,
        stretch: 30,
        depth: 100,
        modifier: 5,
        slideShadows: true
    },
    navigation: {
        prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev",
        nextEl: ".swiper-button-next"
    },
    pagination: {
        el: ".swiper-pagination",
        clickable: false
    }
});
```

```css
html,
body {
    position: relative;
    height: 100vh;
}

body {
    background: #eee;
    font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #000;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background: #000;
}

.swiper {
    max-width: 600px;
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 50px !important;
}

.swiper-slide {
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 320px !important;
    height: 200px !important;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 8px;
}
.swiper-slide.swiper-slide-visible.swiper-slide-active {
    transition: all 0.3s !important;
}
.swiper-slide-visible.swiper-slide-next,
.swiper-slide-visible.swiper-slide-prev {
    transition: all 0.5s !important;
}
.swiper-slide img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}
.swiper-controller {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 80px;
    display: flex;
    gap: 10px;
    /*   justify-content: space-between; */
    z-index: 1111;
}
.swiper-button-next {
    margin-right: 150px;
}
.swiper-button-prev {
    margin-left: 150px;
}
.slider-arrow {
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 30px !important;
    height: 30px !important;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: #fff;
}
.slider-arrow::after {
    content: "";
}
.slider-arrow .icon {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 11111111111;
    color: black;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 500;
    pointer-events: all;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.swiper-pagination {
    transform: translateY(50%) !important;
}
.swiper-pagination-bullet {
    width: 10px !important;
    height: 4px !important;
    border-radius: 4px !important;
    transition: all 0.3s;
    background: #ffffff;
}
.swiper-pagination-bullet-active {
    width: 20px !important;
    background: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/9.2.4/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@20..48,100..700,0..1,-50..200" />

<!-- Swiper -->
<div class="swiper mySwiper">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <div class="swiper-slide">
            <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-2.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
            <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-3.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
            <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-4.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
            <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-5.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
            <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-6.jpg" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-controller">
        <div class="slider-controller">
            <div class="swiper-button-prev slider-arrow">
                <span class="material-symbols-outlined icon ">
                    arrow_back
                </span>
            </div>

            <div class="swiper-button-next slider-arrow">
                <span class="material-symbols-outlined icon">
                    arrow_forward
                </span>
            </div>

            <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>

        </div>
    </div>
```